# Powershell: Get-Process won't return remote description

Tags: powershell

So I'm trying to return a list of running process' descriptions on a machine which I can do no problem via `get-process | select description`

However, when I try: `get-process  -computer remote | select description` nothing is returned, only empty strings.

Is there a reason for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe with WMI and the GetVersionInfo method:

```
$ComputerName = 'server1'

Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -ComputerName $ComputerName | 
Select-Object Name, @{n='Description';e={ [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo( ($_.ExecutablePath -replace '^(.):',"\\$ComputerName\$`1$")).FileDescription }}
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, if you take a look at how the description is retrieved, it will all get clearer:

```
PS> gps | gm | where {$_.name -eq 'description'} | select Definition


   TypeName: System.Diagnostics.Process

Definition
----------
System.Object Description {get=$this.Mainmodule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription;}
```

This accesses `Process.MainModule` for which the documentation has to say that it throws a `NotSupportedExcetion` in the following case:

> You are trying to access the MainModule property for a process that is running on a remote computer. This property is available only for processes that are running on the local computer.

So the attempt to retrieve the description fails for remote processes.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with `get-process` I wrote the below script to show what it 'viewable' via a remote session

get-process -computer computer | select * | where {$_.name -match "tskmgr"}